# Adding a final keyword in the Java main method parameter doesn't give any compile error / exception?

Tags: java

Adding a final keyword in the main method parameter works fine. Why does it not give any compiler error / exception since I have modified the standard main method of Java?

```
 public class StackOverFlow {

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        System.out.println("Hi");

    }
}
```

Now see if I code:

```
public class StackOverFlow {

    public static void main (String... args) {
        
        String[] str = {"I ", "haven't ", "received ", "my ", "answer." };
        args[0] = "hi";
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        args =str;
        for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(args[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

For the above coding when you run the program by passing an argument as:

```
javac StackOverFlow Nisrin
```

My program output is

```
hi
```

I haven’t received my answer.

Now the same thing with the `final` keyword

```
public class StackOverFlow {

    public static void main (final String... args) {
        
        String[] str = {"I ", "haven't ", "received ", "my ", "answer." };
        args[0] = "hi";
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        args =str;
        for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(args[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

It gives me an error: the final parameter, `args`, may not be assigned.

Because now I am assigning `str` to `args`.

This means I have done a big difference by adding the `final` keyword in the parameter and making it constant in the main method, the very entry-point of a Java Program. I am changing the signature of the main method. Then why am I not getting any compile error or runtime error?

Comment: @Andreas Ok I do understand that args is an Object String array so it is final/constant but it does not make every single elements in it constant. But my question is of I am changing the signature of main method.

Comment: The fact that you can still run the program after adding `final` shows that you did not change the *signature*. The signature is determined by the *method name*, and the *parameter types*. Parameter modifiers (`final` and annotations) don't matter.

Answer (score 6):

`final` marks the reference as constant. It doesn't actually change the type. Also note changing the signature of `main` is **never** a compiler error, but it can frequently cause a **runtime** error.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "it can frequently cause a runtime error."

Comment: I mean, if you change the signature of `main` to no longer be an entry-point the code will still compile. You just won't be able to run it. Thus a runtime error (not a compiler error).

Comment: Ok, so you mean that it doesn't remain a main method any more which the JRE can use it to run the program. Please do make a point to check my modified question and kindly guide.

Answer (score 0):

`final` only tells that *"the reference is a constant. Don't try to change it"*. That means so far the `main` method can use it properly.

The `args` parameter is usually used for getting information from the execute command. You may never have any reason to change its value in your program any more.